# Unable to retain login credentials across pages while using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am pretty new to using `urllib` and `requests` module in python. I am trying to access a wikipage in my company's website which requires me to provide my login credentials through a pop up window when I try to access it through a browser.

I was able to write the following script to successfully access the webpage and read it using the following piece of code:

```
import sys
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import getpass
import http.cookiejar

wiki_page = 'http://wiki.company.com/wiki_page'
top_level_url = 'http://login.company.com/'

username = input("Enter Username: ")
password = getpass.getpass('Enter Password: ')

# Authenticate with login server and fetch the wiki page
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)
handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj),handler)
opener.open(wiki_page)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

with urllib.request.urlopen(wiki_page) as response:
    # Do something
```

But now I need to use `requests` module to do the same. I tried using several methods including sessions but could not get it to work. The following is the piece of code which I think close to the actual solution but it gives Response 200 in the first print and Response 401 in the second print:

```
s = requests.Session()
print(s.post('http://login.company.com/', auth=(username, password)))  # I have tried s.post() as well as s.get() in this line
print(s.get('http://wiki.company.com/wiki_page'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site uses the Basic Auth authorization scheme; you'll need to send the login credentials with each request.

Set the [`Session.auth` attribute](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#sessionapi) to a tuple with the username and password on the session:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = (username, password)

response = s.get('http://wiki.company.com/wiki_page')
print(response.text)
```

The `urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()` object would normally only respond to challenges on URLs that *start* with `http://login.company.com/` (so any deeper path will do too), and not send the password elsewhere.

If the simple approach (setting `Session.auth`) doesn't work, you'll need to find out what response is returned by accessing `http://wiki.company.com/wiki_page` directly, which is what your original code *does*. If the server *redirects* you to a login page, where you *then* use the Basic Auth information, you can replicate that:

```
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get('http://wiki.company.com/wiki_page', allow_redirects=False)
if response.status_code in (302, 303):
    target = response.headers['location']
    authenticated = s.get(target, auth=(username, password))
    # continue on to the wiki again
    response = s.get('http://wiki.company.com/wiki_page')
```

You'll have to investigate carefully what responses you get from the server. Open up an interactive console and see what responses you get back. Look at `response.status_code` and `response.headers` and `response.text` for hints. If you leave `allow_redirects` to the default `True`, look at `response.history` to see if there were any intermediate redirections.

Comment: Hi Martin, i tried it but it didnt work I tried this: `s = requests.Session()
s.auth = (username, password)
print(s.get('http://login.company.com/'))
print(s.get('http://wiki.company.com/wiki_page'))` still got the same issue

Comment: Also not sure whether this might be helpful or not but in the first working code if i replace `top_level_url` in the line `password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)` with `wiki_page ` it wont work. I get the same 401 there as well

Comment: @Pulimon: you should not need to go to `login.company.com`.

Comment: @Pulimon: the password manager in `urllib` implements a full challenge-response system, which isn't really needed for Basic Authentication. It could be that the system uses a redirect to `login.company.com` that then sets a cookie, after which the basic auth is no longer needed.

Comment: @Pulimon: perhaps you need to look closely at what happens in the network tab of your browser when you log in; open the browser development tools, go to the network tab, look at document interactions only. Log in.

Comment: Ok wait I have no clue how to decode what happens in that section. What I did see in the network tab is one document with initiator = wiki_page, and request url = (login.company.com/<a lot of gibberish>) The response is an html about 1000 lines long. Could you let me know how to make sense of the document interactions?

Comment: That does sound like a redirect is happening from one page to the next. The login page contents won't matter there, just that a challenge (40x) result is given after the redirect.

Comment: Was finally able to get it working Martijn. Thanks a lot for your help :)